# How to change the "category" of an enterprise-level iPhone app in iTunes from "Unknown Genre" to something more meaningful?

Tags: iphone, itunes

I have an enterprise app (thus not available to the general public in the App Store) that I have developed.  When I put it into iTunes, it shows the nice icon (thanks to iTunesArtwork), but it displays "Unknown Genre" underneath it.  How do I change this "category" (not sure what exactly to call this) to something else (and is there list of "genres" I can pick from?)  Hopefully this is something that I set before I build.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by creating a iTunesMetadata.plist file and putting it inside your IPA file.  It goes at the same level as your iTunesArtwork.  I don't think Apple documents the fields in this file, so go grab one from from an IPA file from the App Store (they are really ZIP files with an IPA extension) and modify it to suit your needs.

The field you are going to specifically want to change is the Genre field.  In my own experiments, I found that you can remove some of the fields if they aren't applicable.  You will just have to play with the file until you find something that works for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

To change the category log in to iTunes connect go to "Manage Your Applications" then click on your app and you'll see "Edit Information".  Scroll down a little bit and it will say "Primary Category"...

To change keywords you have to submit an update because Apple checks those.

Comment: It's an enterprise app, I'm not sure but it sounds like it is not being distributed through iTunes Connect.

Comment: oic.. well, that's makes the question a little harder then doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah, it's an enterprise app.  The answer given works for the user, but as the developer, I'd like have to the Primary Category already set when the user drags the app into iTunes.  I haven't been able to find any documentation on this.

Comment: My bet is that the answer is that you can't do it.  On app store apps apple is adding the category when they approve it, which would leave me to believe that it's not something that you could do yourself without some sort of TOS-breaking hack.

Answer (score 0):

Piggy-backing off what @Dennis Munsie said, the iTunesMetadata.plist file is what you need to edit (or create).
See [this blog post](http://brianmilton.javaproductions.net/?page_id=290). Basically, for me, I was able to get by with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>genre</key>
 <string>Productivity</string>
 <key>itemName</key>
 <string>NAME OF APP</string> 
</dict>
</plist>
```

..I had to specify "itemName" as the name of my app. Otherwise, the filename of the .ipa file was displayed in the iTunes app area, and I didn't want that.

Comment: It still works for me. For me, i place the iTunesMetadata.plist at the root of .ipa file on the same level as the "Payload" folder. (I don't know if it works if you place it on same level as iTunesArtwork like Dennis said..perhaps that is the issue)